# Regex for all odd length string that contains exactly 2 0's with language {0,1}

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I just started learning about formal lang and automata theory, and recently learned about regex, so I don't know any complicated symbols, so please stick with basic symbols.

The question is: Write a regex for the following language over {0,1} that is a set of all odd length strings that contain exactly two 0's.

I've got the first part finished (the odd part), it should be:

(0+1)[(0+1)(0+1)]* ( + is the same as | (or) I believe, we learnt it as +)

However, when I think about having exactly two 0's it gets really messed up. I can only see that I can use * with 1 only since # of 0's are limited to 2. But if i do (11)* , I can't get the permutation of 0's inside the 1's. (e.g. can't get 10101 with (11)*).

What I know:

1. Only 1's can use *
2. In the regex only two 0's will be used
3. The way to make odd length is to add an odd length to an even length
   (even length needs to have empty string within it's set)
4. Odd length should not use * since 2 odd = even, so only even length
   can use *

For possible hints or answer, please use 0,1,+/|,*,(,) only. Some other expressions I will not be able to understand.

Comment: Related questions http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11787/designing-a-regular-expression-for-the-set-of-all-binary-that-contain-strings-wi and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/regular-expression-for-binary-words-with-few-zeros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** You did a good start, except maybe for (4). Note that $(11)^*1$ is a regular expression for the set of words of odd length (on the alphabet $\{1\}$). Does that help you?

**Hint 2.** Consider a word in your language. You know you have exactly two $0$ and hence your word is of the form $1^i01^j01^k$ for some $i, j, k \geqslant 0$ such that $i + j + k$ is an odd number.

**Answer** $(11)^*10(11)^*10(11)^*1 + (11)^*10(11)^*0(11)^* + (11)^*0(11)^*10(11)^* + (11)^*0(11)^*0(11)^*1$

Comment: what do u mean by except 4. 4 is saying if u kleene closure an odd length string, then you have rotation between even and odd every time. e.g. (111)* = 111, 111111, 111111111 which is odd, even, odd.

Comment: I only said "maybe (4)" because I was not sure whether you realized what I said about $(11)^*1$. This RE for odd length makes use of $*$, contrary to your statement "Odd length should not use *".

Comment: If you read, I said I already figured out the odd part. Meaning I know I need to kleene closure on even length string (e.g. (11)*). (4) is stating that you can only use kleene closure on even length string because if you kleene closure on odd length string you can't get ONLY ODD LENGTH STRING requirement. I appreciate you replying to my question, but it doesn't help a single bit, you wrote what I have already figured out which is stated in the question.

Comment: Just so this doesn't confuse I'm saying you need to kleene closure even length + concatenate an odd length string. (e.g. (11)*1, (1111)*1, (11)*111)

Comment: I have added a second hint to my first answer. Does it help you?

Comment: A little bit, I wanted to build a regex somewhat close to that, but what I currently think is that I should make a kleene closure with only 1's and each and every kleene closure must be a pair (e.g. (11)*, (1111)*, (111111)*, and so on). however every pair has it's limit due to the fact I can't do the most simple one: 010. I don't see how I can kleene closure in 1 alphabet...

Comment: Wait, it helped more than I thought. I'm thinking along the lines of some regex that would look like.. (1(11)*)0(1(11)*)0(1(11)*), but still it's not the general case as it requires at least 1 bewteen the 0's if I put empty string, (e+1(11)*) for each then you could possibly have 00... so hmmm...

Comment: You are getting close to the solution. Basically, you treated the case where $i$, $j$ and $k$ are odd numbers in Hint 2. What are the other possible cases to have $i + j + k$ odd?

Comment: Well, I guess the problem is pretty much solved, if I used exhaustive method (considering all permutation of two 0's ans 1's). E.g. (1(11)*)0(1(11)*)0(1(11)*) + (1(11)*)00 + 0(1(11)*0 + 00(1(11)*) + ... so and so forth.... I'm assuming you know the answer. How long is the ans? Cause I think it's possible to simplify this ans...